# Create History Tables - Ebean ORM Java PlayFramework

Tags: java, orm, playframework, ebean

Hello I'm trying to create and use history tables as per ebean orm instructions my code is as below for the model

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;


@History
@Entity
public class LegalStuff extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String body;
}
```

On compile i get the error below.

```
    play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[cannot find symbol
  symbol: class History]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
```

I need to track the history of the data in the above tables. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Playframework to Version 2.5.x
Ebean set to 3.0.0 in Sbt-play-ebean...

This is because @History is not supported in sbt-play-ebean 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the compile error you should provide the correct import for the `@History` [annotation](http://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/History.html):

`import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.History;`

Comment: Upgrade Playframework to Version 2.5.x Ebean set to 3.0.0 in Sbt-play-ebean...

This is because @History is not supported in sbt-play-ebean 1.0.0